# jQuery loop with JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm sending some JSON data to an Ajax function, this is what the data looks like:

```
{"one": 21, "two": 10, "three": 19, "four": 100}
```

Using jQuery, I would now like to show this data inside an `<h3>` tag. For example, I would like to have all the `one, two, ...` on one side. Here is what I tried:

```
 $.ajax({
  url: $("#container").attr("data-url"),
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        $('#test').text(key);
    });
  }
});
```

**Html**

```
<h3 id="test"></h3>
```

The problem with this code is that it only shows the first occurrence of the array, in this case, I will only see "`one`". Can someone help me find what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: That is an object, not an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overwriting the element each time through the loop. You need to concatenate all the keys and then put that in the element.

```
success: function(data) {
    var text = Object.keys(data).join(', ');
    $('#test').text(text);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting the key in each loop. You need to add all them to a variable then print that. Since you want them all on one side (which is vertically), then you need to separate them by line breaks and add them using `html()` instead of `text()`;

```
var t = '';
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
    t += key + '<br/>';
});
$('#test').html(t);
```

I assume you want the values too on the other side. Let's say you want to separate the keys and values by the equal sign:

```
var t = '';
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
    t += key + ' = ' + val + '<br/>';
});
$('#test').html(t);
```

Comment: Yeah indeed. The problem is that i was overwriting. I need to make more practice with Jquery. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
url: $("#container").attr("data-url"),
dataType: 'json',
success: function (data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        $('#test').append(key + ', ');
    });
}
});
```

Just use $('#test').append instead of $('#test').text to keep the keys added previously